# Is there a way to catch when I'm using a laravel tinker session to fiddle with the Models in an Observer class?

Tags: laravel, observers, tinker

I have an `Observer` set up to Listen to a `Model`'s events in order to keep my `Controller` clean of Logging messages. My implementation is as follows:

First, a store method that does just what it's supposed to do. Create and save a new model from valid parameters.

```php
# app/Http/Controllers/ExampleController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreExample;
use App\Example;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Create and save an Example from validated form parameters.
     * @param  App\Http\Requests\StoreExample  $request
     */
    public function store(StoreExample $request)
    {
        Example::create($request->validated());

        return back();
    }
}
```

The `StoreExample` Form Request isn't important. It just validates and checks a gate to authorize the action.

The `Observer` I have set up logs this action.

```php
# app/Observers/ExampleObserver.php
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Example;

class ExampleObserver
{
    public function created(Example $example): void
    {
        \Log::info(auth()->id()." (".auth()->user()->full_name.") has created Example with params:\n{$example}");
    }
}
```

The problem I have, is the way my logs depend on the `auth()` object to be set. Given the `auth` middleware and the gate it has to check in order to store an Example, there is no way a guest user will set off this code.

However, I do like to use `tinker` in my local and staging environments to check the behavior of the site but that can set off an error (Well, `PHP notice` to be more precise) because I can create `Example` models without being authenticated and the logger will try to fetch the property `full_name` from the non-object `auth()->user()`.

So my question is as follows: Is there a way to catch when I'm specifically using the Laravel `tinker` session to handle my models in the Observer class?

Comment: Well, this isn't a proper response to your question but it seems that you want to log and check different aspects of your app to validate the correct behavior so.. have you tried the [Laravel Telescope package](https://laravel.com/docs/telescope)? This will record automatically all the request, payload, database queries, events, and more. This could help you to achieve the results that you want.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I might in the future™. I don't really have trouble with logging. I just want to know if it's possible to identify when a model operation was done from a tinker session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, replying to my own question: There **IS** a way. It requires using a `Request` object. <s>Since observers do not deal with requests on their own, I injected one in the constructor.</s> **request() can be used instead, so no DI is needed.**

## Why is a Request important?

Because a request object has an accessible $server attribute that has the information I want. This is the relevant information I get by returning a `dd($request->server)` (I'm not gonna paste the whole thing. My Request's ServerBag has over 100 attributes!)

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#37
  #parameters: array:123 [
    "SERVER_NAME" => "localhost"
    "SERVER_PORT" => 8000
    "HTTP_HOST" => "localhost:8000"
    "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Symfony"   // Relevant
    "REMOTE_ADDR" => "127.0.0.1"
    "SCRIPT_NAME" => "artisan"       // Relevant
    "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "artisan"   // Relevant
    "PHP_SELF" => "artisan"          // Relevant
    "PATH_TRANSLATED" => "artisan"   // Relevant
    "argv" => array:2 [              // Relevant
      0 => "artisan"
      1 => "tinker"
    ]
    "argc" => 2
  ]
}
```

So there's all these attributes I can filter by using `$request->server('attribute')` (returns `$request->server->attribute` or `null`, so no risk of accessing an undefined property). I can also do `$request->server->has('attribute')` (returns `true` or `false`)

```php
# app/Observers/ExampleObserver.php
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Example;

class ExampleObserver
{
    /* Since we can use request(), there's no need to inject a Request into the constructor
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    */

    public function created(Example $example): void
    {
        \Log::info($this->getUserInfo()." has created Example with params:\n{$example}");
    }

    private function getUserInfo(): string
    {
        // My logic here. 
    }
}
```

Comment: Good find! I needed this as well. I did this in the app service provider
`config()->set('app.tinker',request()->server->get('argv')[1] === 'tinker');`
So now I can access it everywhere in my application